# jQuery function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my piece of code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Shout!</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var status=1;
function action() {



if(status==1) {
$("#Layer1").hide("slow");
$("#Layer3").hide("fast");
$("#Layer4").hide("slow");
$("#close").attr("src","open.jpg");
status=0;

}

else if(status==0) {
status=1;
$("#Layer1").show("slow");
$("#Layer3").show("fast");
$("#Layer4").show("slow");
$("#close").attr("src","close.jpg");

}




}


function sendline() {

$("#msg").val(" ");

}

function type() {
var text=$("#msg").val();

$("#Layer6").html(text);

}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
    body {
 background-color: #000000;
    }
    #Layer1 {
 position:absolute;
 width:200px;
 height:115px;
 z-index:1;
 left: 179px;
 top: 3px;
    }
    #Layer2 {
 position:absolute;
 width:69px;
 height:64px;
 z-index:2;
 left: 570px;
 top: 543px;
    }
    #Layer3 {
 position:absolute;
 width:124px;
 height:22px;
 z-index:3;
 left: 473px;
 top: 474px;
    }
    .style1 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: "Segoe UI";
 font-weight: bold;
    }
    #Layer4 {
 position:absolute;
 width:72px;
 height:27px;
 z-index:4;
 left: 744px;
 top: 485px;
    }
    #Layer5 {
 position:absolute;
 width:274px;
 height:70px;
 z-index:5;
 left: 422px;
 top: 62px;
    }
    #Layer6 {
 position:absolute;
 width:638px;
 height:356px;
 z-index:5;
 left: 272px;
 top: 105px;
    }
-->
</style></head>

<body>
<div class="style1" id="Layer3">
<textarea id="msg" style="height:50px;width:250px" rows="10" cols="80" onkeyup="type()"></textarea></div>
<div id="Layer1">Hello World!<img src="body.jpg" alt="Shout !" width="842" height="554" /></div>
<div id="Layer2"><img src="close.jpg" id="close" width="63" height="64" OnClick="action()"/></div>
<div id="Layer4">
<input type="button" value="Send Line" onclick="sendline()" /></div>
<div id="Layer6" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm facing a problem with the type() function.Its simply not running

Any advice on how to get it rnnning?

Thanks!

Comment: You're using jQuery in combination with inline event handlers? Blasphemy!

Comment: umm,the sendline() function works just fine! :S

Comment: It works fine on my desktop! :S . And what's the problem if we use it that way ? I've seen such examples in books like AJAX and jQuery for dummies. It should work

Comment: There's no *real* problem with inline event handlers, except it doesn't really follow with unobtrusive JavaScript and a clear separation of behavioural logic from markup. In addition, it registers more event handlers with the DOM than jQuery and this I believe makes it more prone to memory leaks when manipulating the DOM, an example of which might be removing elements from the DOM without not having first detached the event handlers registered for them.

Comment: Thanks! is there any way that would help me to do the same thing ? i mean can i use jquery and javascript together ?
pardon me! but i'm a beginner!

Comment: You look to me to already be using jQuery - the calls to `$(...)` look like jQuery function calls. Since jQuery is JavaScript, using JavaScript with JavaScript is fine :) Just be careful about overriding global object properties used by the library and you'll be fine.

Comment: updated the posted code here - http://jsfiddle.net/jR4zJ/2/ . Forgot to add reference to jQuery (and also added in some images).

Comment: @Russ - be careful when making a fiddle, you have to include jQuery and *not* use an onLoad wrapper, otherwise his functions won't be available outside that scope.

Comment: I replaced the jQuery by

function type() {
var text= getElementById("msg");
var box=getElementById("Layer6");

box.innerHTML=text.value;

It doesn't seem to work :/

THanks for all the help! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Nick - good call, have edited the previous comment. I'm not used to do dealing with functions that need to be callable by inline event handlers :)

Comment: @Anant Here's an example of how to use jQuery to bind event handlers instead of using the inline event handlers: http://jsfiddle.net/hhZ8P/2/ (look at the bottom of the javascript section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is running, however it's throwing an error because of the function name:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** string is not a function

or in Firefox:

> type is not a function

In short, you can't use `type` as a function name here, you just need to give it a slightly different name, for exampled `typed`.

[Here's your code *only* changing the function name](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vLU7b/), working :)

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `type` function to something else (try `somethingElseThanType` just to test), and it should work