# I keep getting a "Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function" error, even though my code seems to be fine. Can anyone have a look and explain?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script language = javascript>
    show = function()
    {
         document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = window.opener.game.pl.guild.n;
         var app = document.getElementById("app");
         var apps = window.opener.game.pl.guild.app;

         for (a in apps)
         {
              var appAdd = document.createElement("option");
              appAdd.text = apps[a];
              appAdd.value = apps[a];

              app.add(appAdd);
         }
    }

    accept = function()
    {
        console.log("Accepting");
        var app = document.getElementById("app");

        window.opener.input.options = "acceptApp";
        window.opener.input.an = app.options[app.selectedIndex].value;
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = "show()">
        <h1 id = "name" align = "center"> ### </h1>
    <div style="text-align:center">
            <p>You own this guild.</p>
        </div>
    </br>

        <p>Applications:</p>
        <select id = "app"></select>

        <input type = "button" onclick = "accept()" value = "Accept application" />
     </body>
</html>
```

Every time a user clicks the button, the **accept** function should be called. There's nothing wrong with the function itself, I'm sure about that. The function **show** that gets called when this starts just fills the selection with options, and **create** just sends it to the server.

Comment: I haven't seen HTML written like this since 1992! Well, you might be "sure about that", but I'd like to see your Javascript, please. Better still -- SHOW A TESTCASE

Comment: Show the code.  Where is the accept method defined?

Comment: OK, I will, the battery on my laptop just died so give me some time (I'm writing this from my PC). Also, @LightnessRacesinOrbit, what's wrong with my HTML?

Comment: @bane: All those spaces around `=`! Also, writing Javascript inside your HTML is considered poor form. And I have no idea what `</br>` is.

Comment: Here, the code has been added. Also, doesn't `</br>` make a line break?

Comment: So, if it's uncaught, how about `catch`ing the `Error`? Firebug will tell you which line if you do!

Comment: You shouldn't use `<br />` to make some empty space, you should put a `margin-bottom` on your `<div class="guild-status">` -- then use CSS (in a separate file) to apply both the bottom margin and the `text-align:center`

Comment: missing && in function can cose this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should put a semi-colon after the function call in your events:

```
 onload = "show();"

 onclick = "accept();"
```

Edit: I also see in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852237/cant-use-download-as-a-function-name-in-javascript) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431635/jquery-function-error) SO questions that there can be **problems with function names** that cause this exact error message. Just for fun, you might try renaming your functions...

Comment: Good practice, but I don't think that's the answer to this problem.

Comment: I will check that as soon as my laptop goes back online, but I doubt that's the answer, just as @RoryMcCrossan said. I do stuff like this on other spots as well, and there are no errors there.

Comment: Oh wow, it worked! But why doesn't naming a function "accept" work? Does `onclick = "accept();"` do something else?

Comment: It's kind of a mystery, as we see in the linked articles. I didn't see a definitive list of excluded keywords. Go figure. I am so glad you found your solution though, however illogical it may seem.

Comment: You may want to consider attaching these event handlers with JS to avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: I have watched for ours to my js and I would never found this my self. After I read your edit I saw that I had a var called confirm after that I called the function confirm. By changing the var name to con It worked again! Great!!!

Comment: My error was caused by duplicate function names.  Thanks for solving it.

Answer (score 15):

I have met the same question. 
Then I figured it out that "download" is one of  the reserved words of Chrome.
So I have to change the name of my javascript method.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with "translate".

Comment: This is why you avoid globals ;)

Comment: `chat` is also reserved :-)

Answer (score 6):

I think I know the root of the problem - I use AJAX to dynamically populate my page with HTML that is stored in variables. I had the exact same problem when I named my function the same as my variable, it would seem as if the browser was trying to run the variable as a function. For instance:

```
var callthis = 'fjdashfkjdh';
function callthis() {
    alert(callthis);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="callthis();" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Clicking the button will cause the Javascript parser to run through the Javascript code, and when it hits the first line it runs the variable instead of seeking a function. This is perhaps a bug in Javascript itself because it should look for the first function with the same name, not the first name which is equal to the function to be called e.g. `callthis();`.

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when using variables with popular names.

The variable z, for example, is used by jQuery Mobile. If you are using the same variable name and using a jQuery mobile widget, your use of the variable will be overwritten.

Better to avoid globals, of course. Better still to choose variable names not likely to lead to conflicts. `Var zZz` for example.